# Passing an async function to a confirmation modal in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a few action buttons in a table in react. Buttons are for disabling and enabling users in the firebase database.

I have the firebase logic in a component called `Users.jsx` everything works fine; however, I want to add a confirmation modal before the async function is called.

my handler function for disabling a user, for example,  in `Users.jsx` is this

```
  // Disable user
  const handleDisableUser = async uid => {
    try {
      const disableUser = httpsCallable(functions, 'disableUser');
      await disableUser({ uid });
      const userRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
      await updateDoc(userRef, {
        isDisabled: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Currently the button in the table triggering the function is:

```
<IconButton
 disabled={user.data.isDisabled}
 color='error'
 onClick={() => handleDisableUser(user.id)}
 >
 <PersonOffIcon />
</IconButton>
```

However, I want this function to be triggered in a modal when the user clicks "I confirm" button.

I tried creating a state for the confirmation modal like this:

```
 const [isConfirmationOpen, setIsConfirmationOpen] = useState(false);
 const [confirmationText, setConfirmationText] = useState(null);
 const [confirmationAction, setConfirmationAction] = useState(null);
```

Then created a wrapper function to open the modal and passed `handleDisableUser` to the state:

```
  const handleDisableUserWrapper = uid => {
    setConfirmationText('Are you sure you want to disable this user?');
    setConfirmationAction(() => handleDisableUser(uid));
    setIsConfirmationOpen(true);
  };
```

However, when adding this state in the modal it's still null!

```
 <Button variant='contained' onClick={confirmationAction}>
```

There must be a way to do this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in

```
setConfirmationAction(() => handleDisableUser(uid));
```

Passing function as argument to state setter method has different meaning. You are supposed to use it like

```
setState((previous) => doSomethingOn(previous))
```

Where `doSomethingOn` returns a modified version of `previous`

Instead of attempting to save callback function `() => handleDisableUser(uid)`, you can maintain `uid` on a state.

`const [confirmingUid, setConfirmingUid] = useState(null)`

On confirmation modal, You can call `handleDisableUser(confirmingUid)`